# How to get the user object when the user is logged in and None otherwise?

Tags: python, fastapi

How to get the user object if the user is logged in and None otherwise?

Following the [FastAPI documentation for getting the user](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/get-current-user/#create-a-get_current_user-dependency) the `/api_limits` endpoint below returns a 401 when the user is not logged in (in an application with proper jwt signatures).

```
from typing import Optional

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")


class User(BaseModel):
    username: str
    email: Optional[str] = None
    full_name: Optional[str] = None
    disabled: Optional[bool] = None


def fake_decode_token(token):
    return User(
        username=token + "fakedecoded", email="john@example.com", full_name="John Doe"
    )


async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    user = fake_decode_token(token)
    return user


@app.get("/api_limits")
async def read_users_me(current_user: User = Depends(get_current_user)):
    if current_user is None:
        return 2
    return 5
```

How to get the `current_user` user object inside the `/api_limits` endpoint in the sample code above to be `None` when the user is not logged in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `OAuth2PasswordBearer` [automagically generates a 401 error](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/22528373bba6a654323de416ad5c867cbadb81bb/fastapi/security/oauth2.py#L155) if no `Authorization` header is present at all (i.e. there is no valid token being submitted).

If you don't want this to happen, you can set `auto_error=False` - in which case it will return `None` instead if no header is found. You can then change your `get_current_user` method to return `None` instead of a user if no token is present:

```
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token", auto_error=False)

...

async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    if not token:
        return None

    user = fake_decode_token(token)
    return user
```